# Why is DriveApp `FileIterator.next` in Google AppScript Getting The Same Files Over And Over Again?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

So I'm trying to query my image files inside my gDrive. This is my code.

```
    const imageFiles = [];
    const folders = [];
    while (parentFolder.hasNext()) {
        const pF = parentFolder.next();
        const subFolders = pF.getFolders();
        while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
            const sF = subFolders.next();
            if (sF.getName() === 'IMAGES') {
                folders.push(sF.getName());
                const imageFileIt = sF.getFiles();
                while (imageFileIt.hasNext()) {
                    const imageFile = imageFileIt.next();
                    imageFiles.push({ name: imageFile.getName(), url: imageFile.getUrl(), id: imageFile.getId() });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This works fine when I run it inside the script editor. But when I deploy it and run through my deployed gdoc addon it gets the same file the same number of images in my drive. For example, say if I have a.jpeg, b.jpeg, c.jpeg in my drive folder, this code in the deployed gdoc addon will give me a.jpeg, a.jpeg, a.jpeg. Why is this? It seems it next is not actually going to the next item.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase someone runs into the same issue. It seems I have replaced all the `const` into `var`s and it works now. Interesting that it doesn't give me any errors. Yea I don't know if this is the real solution for something with deploy configuration to allow for those keywords.